# How to stack 2 ul-navbar in right navbar bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I try to make another menu on top of my right menu with bootstrap 4.6

My idea is create:
2 `navbar-nav` with class `w-100` and `float-right` , so its would be 100% width and floating to right.

but thats not happened.

The red box is my current progress, and the green box is my target.

[image: RED box is my current html and GREEN box is my target]

Here it is what I tried so far:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img height="50" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x75/000/fff&text=LOGO" alt=""></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 float-right">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FACEBOOK ICON</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">TWITTER ICON</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 float-right">
                <li class="nav-item active ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">DOCUMENTATION</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">EXAMPLES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">THEME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">EXPO</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `w-100` and `float-right` classes and include the [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/) classes from Bootstrap. I have explained the replacements in the comments.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img height="50" src="https://dummyimage.com/150x75/000/fff&text=LOGO" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column align-items-end" id="navbarCollapse"> <!-- flex-direction: column and align-items: end properties by these two classes -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav"> <!-- Removed width so that it does not occupy full width and float is not needed -->
      <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">FACEBOOK ICON</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">TWITTER ICON</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav"> <!-- Removed width so that it does not occupy full width and float is not needed -->
      <li class="nav-item active ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">DOCUMENTATION</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">EXAMPLES</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">THEME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">EXPO</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">BLOG</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```